# How to use env vars declared in a GitHub Actions workflow .yml later in the file (in the same env section)?

Tags: github-actions

How would I use env vars declared in a GitHub Actions workflow .yml later in the file (in the same `env` section)?

I have some base env vars set (4), and wish to use those values in a subsequent env var declaration, but cannot seem to get this to work.

For example, I want to accomplish the following:

```yaml
name: build-push-docker-image

# ...

  - name: docker push
    env:
      AWS_ACCT_ID: 123457890123
      AWS_REGION: us-west-2
      DOCKER_IMG_NAME=test-github-actions-push-ecr
      DOCKER_IMG_TAG: latest

      # The following does not work (env vars do not expand).
      # How would I use the env vars set above to have TARGET eval to what is expected?
      TARGET: ${AWS_ACCT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${DOCKER_IMG_NAME}:${DOCKER_IMG_TAG}
    run: |
      docker tag ${DOCKER_IMG_NAME}:${DOCKER_IMG_TAG} ${TARGET} 
      docker push ${TARGET}
```

Comment: According to `env` [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env), "**Variables in the `env` map cannot be defined in terms of other variables in the map.**".

Comment: @ Azeem, what suggestion would you have to accomplish what I hope to achieve here?  Is there another approach?  Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do nesting however you can simply define a variable inside the `run` section and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do such thing, but not when those are in the same scope.
Instead you can define the environment variables as per the job, and not per the step, then use the values where you need it.

```
jobs:
    example:
        name: Example
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        env:
            AWS_ACCT_ID: 123457890123
            AWS_REGION: us-west-2

        steps:
          - name: docker push
            env:
              AWS_ACCT_ID: $AWS_ACCT_ID
              AWS_REGION: $AWS_REGION
              TARGET: ${AWS_ACCT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${DOCKER_IMG_NAME}:${DOCKER_IMG_TAG}
```

Or, you could define those "shared" ones as GitHub secrets for your action, then use it wherever you want with: `AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}` for example.